# how to handle this kind of statements?

Tags: fortran

I have String variable which will have maximum 80 characters.
I am declaring a variable as `CHARACTER STRING*80` or  `CHARACTER*80 STRING`
If user enters less than 80 characters,then some special characters are getting appended in remaining position.

Could you please let me know how to handle??

CLARIFICATION:
I would like to know how to fill the remaining space in the string with other characters.

Comment: and please clarify that you'd like to fill the remaining space in the string, `80-strlen(string)` with some character

Answer (score 2):

Pre-define your string with an empty one, to fill it with spaces. And afterwards use trim to only get the string without trailing spaces. You should also use character(len=80) in the declaration.

Edit, Update: You can replace the trailing spaces in the string with some other character with something like

```
do i=len_trim(string)+1,len(string)
  string(i:i) = 'A'
end do
```

Comment: Small error, correct declaration is character(len=80). len= may be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand "If user enters less than 80 characters,then some special characters are getting appended in remaining position." -- the Fortran way is to append blanks to fill a string on IO or assignment.    You can see that with the following test program.   It also includes the method shown by haraldkl to change trailing blanks to some other character.   A problem is that it is difficult to distinguish between "real" trailing blanks and ones that are padding.

```
module subs

contains

   subroutine write_string (string)

   character (len=10), intent (in) :: string
   integer :: i

   write (*, '(">", A10, "<")' ) string

   do i=1, 10
      write (*, *) i, ichar (string (i:i))
   end do

   return

end subroutine write_string

end module subs


program test_string

use subs

character (len=10) :: string
integer :: i


!  Assignment test

string = "abc"

call  write_string (string)


!  Read test
string = "123456789"

write (*, '("Input string:")' )
read (*, '(A)' ) string

call write_string (string)



!  replacing the trailing blanks:

do i=len_trim (string)+1, 10
   string(i:i) = "+"
end do

call write_string (string)

stop
end program test_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a string of 80 characters of your choice (say, spaces) and then get input character by character, therefore leaving all elements untouched:

`[' ', ' ', ' ' ... ' ']`

`['h', ' ', ' ' ... ' ']`

`['h', 'e', ' ' ... ' ']`

`['h', 'e', 'l' ... ' ']`